# Java regex to remove everything between character 'i' and ':'

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String

```
"{TEXT=9201i3:9830i22:90400i11:92710i7:94500|HELLO_UK}"
```

and I need to do the following:

1. Remove everything between `i` and `:` and replace it with `,`
2. Remove `{TEXT=`
3. Remove `|HELLO_UK}`

I want to end up with `"9201,9830,90400,92710,94500"`

I've had an attempt at it but it doesn't quite do what I want. The following is what I've written:

```
numbers = numbers.replaceAll("\\D.*?:", ",");
```

I get the following result: `",9830,90400,92710,94500|HELLO_UK}"`

Notice how it has removed the first set of numbers (9201).

Can anyone suggest the regex I should be using please?

Comment: Try `({TEXT=)|i\\d*:|\\|HELLO_UK}`. Also, there's a neat tool for regexes called [regexr](http://regexr.com/3ei76).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
String str = "{TEXT=9201i3:9830i22:90400i11:92710i7:94500|HELLO_UK}"
        .replaceAll("(\\{TEXT=|\\|HELLO_UK\\})", "")
        .replaceAll("i(.*?):", ",");

System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris Shchegolev!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following :

```
String str = "{TEXT=9201i3:9830i22:90400i11:92710i7:94500|HELLO_UK}";
str.replaceAll("[(A-Z)*{|}_=]", "")
   .replaceAll("[i:]", ",");

System.out.println(str);
```

Output will be

```
9201,3,9830,22,90400,11,92710,7,94500
```